# Google Webmaster Tools complains about invalid namespace in my sitemap

Tags: google, sitemap, xml

I'm having trouble defining my sitemap to Google's liking. I'm having a hard time testing this, because I can only test the validity of our sitemap using Google Webmaster Tools, when the newest code has been deployed to our production-environment, which can only happen every 3 weeks (every sprint). That is why I am asking here, instead of just testing it myself.

The header of my generated sitemap looks like this (added new-line and indentation for readability):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<urlset xlmns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

When I test my sitemap in Google Webmaster Tools, it tells me that my namespace is invalid, and I don't understand why.

I've found two articles about it, [one from Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668), and [one from sitemaps.org](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html). The Google's example-header looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
```

and the example from sitemaps.org has this header:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<urlset
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd"
xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
```

Mine looks like Google's example, except I have this extra schema include, which was recommended on a third site:

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

Why is mine invalid? Does the include have to be before the namespace? Should it work without this extra include? Or do I actually need everything from the sitemap.org header-example, and in that order?

Thanks!

---

## SOLUTION

Google is (of course) correct. This is what you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<url>
    <loc>some.url.com</loc>
    -- Additional variables if you want them.
</url>
```

I ended up using code something like this (I'm generating the sitemap in C#):

```
// Create a variable holding the sitemap namespace
XNamespace sitemapNs = XNamespace.Get("http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9");

// Create a new standalone XDocument
var xDocument = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"));

// Create the urlset-element
var xElement = new XElement(sitemapNs + "urlset");

// Create a new url-element and add elements to it
var el = new XElement(sitemapNs + "url");
el.Add(new XElement(sitemapNs + "loc", loc));
el.Add(new XElement(sitemapNs + "changefreq", changeFreq));
el.Add(new XElement(sitemapNs + "priority", priority));
el.Add(new XElement(sitemapNs + "lastmod", lastMod));

// Add the url-element to the urlset-element
xElement.Add(el);

// Add the urlset-element to the XDocument
xDocument.Add(xElement);
```

Obviously, I've coded it so I can add several elements easily, and I have separate methods for generation the header and handling the different elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you are using an invalid namespace, the article your followed is outdated and should of never be used. Follow the [W3C XML schema recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/) to get rid of these errors removed. More [explained about the namespace location](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#xsi_schemaLocation).

> [SOURCE](http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance)
>
> XML Schema instance namespace
>       See the XML Schema
>          Recommendation for an introduction
>
> ```
> $Date: 2001/03/16 20:25:57 $
>
> $Id: XMLSchema-instance.xsd,v 1.4 2001/03/16 20:25:57 ht Exp $
>
>
> This schema should never be used as such:
>                 the XML
>                 Schema Recommendation forbids the declaration of
>                 attributes in this namespace
> ```

Use something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="//example.com/sitemap.xsl"?>
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
```

Comment: So I should remove this line?
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

Comment: Remove it. Use something like in my example (answer edited).

Comment: I have added my working code to my question.

Comment: Leaving out the lines:

`xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"`

and

`xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd"`

made several sitemap validators on the web go crazy. Leaving them in, does not seem to affect acceptance with any of the webmaster tools I'm using.